# Count() из трех таблиц с разными условиями, одним запросом

Tags: mysql

Имеем три таблицы `pictures`, `movies`, `stories`. Каждая таблица имеет одинаковые столбцы `status`, `created_at`.

`status` бывает трех видов: `active`, `pending`, `deleted`

Необходимо одним запросом получить кол-во строк созданные за **последний час** и за **последние 24 часа**. Наглядно это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|Status |Pics1h|Pics24h|Mov1h|Mov24h|Stor1h|Stor24h|
----------------------------------------------------
|active | 12   | 30    | 8   | 14   | 20   | 31    |
----------------------------------------------------
|pending|  2   |  4    | 1   | 4    | 2    | 8     |
----------------------------------------------------
|deleted| 10   | 34    | 2   | 45   | 33   | 45    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Один столбец я умею вывести, например:

```
SELECT status, count(*) as `Pics1h`
FROM pictures
WHERE (created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
GROUP BY status;
```

Как получить данные из трех таблиц, возможно и несколькими запросами, но максимально эффективно?

Comment: а подзапросы в запросе не считаются за несколько? иначе просто никак вообще

Comment: можно и подзапросами. главное получить нужный результат, минимальными нагрузками

Comment: Просто напоминание (возможно для @Petr буде полезным): `COUNT(*)` и `COUNT(field)` - это не одно и то же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select status,
       sum(Pics1h) Pics1h, sum(Pics24h) Pics24h,
       sum(Mov1h) Mov1h, sum(Mov24h) Mov24h,
       sum(Stor1h) Stor1h, sum(Stor24h) Stor24h
  from (
        SELECT status, sum(created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) Pics1h, count(1) Pics24h,
               NULL Mov1h, NULL Mov24h, NULL Stor1h, NULL Stor24h
          FROM pictures
         WHERE created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY status
      UNION ALL
        SELECT status, NULL, NULL,
               sum(created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 60 MINUTE), count(1),
               NULL, NULL
          FROM Mov
         WHERE created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY status
      UNION ALL
        SELECT status, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
               sum(created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 60 MINUTE), count(1)
          FROM Stor
         WHERE created_at >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY status
      UNION ALL SELECT 'active', 0,0,0,0,0,0
      UNION ALL SELECT 'pending', 0,0,0,0,0,0
      UNION ALL SELECT 'deleted', 0,0,0,0,0,0
   ) A
  GROUP BY status
```

**UPD** Последние три UNION для того, что бы все строки точно были в результате. Нули можно заменить на NULL, в зависимости от желаемого результата.

Comment: все отлично работает, кроме вариантов, когда например статуса `pending` нет ни за час, ни за 24 часа. В этом случае строка вообще не формируется. Формируются только две `active` и `deleted`

Comment: @Petr Так об этом надо явно сообщать в вопросе, что строки обязаны быть ...