# SQL запрос из нескольких таблиц с результатом в разные столбцы

Tags: mysql

Прошу помощи с запросом mySQL.

Есть несколько таблиц (tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4) в каждой есть столбцы :

| vol | price | date |.

Необходимо вычислить сумму произведений всех строк (итого) каждой таблицы, в разные столбцы в результате, за сегодня.

Запрос SELECT SUM(vol*price) AS Stab1 FROM tab1 WHERE date=Дата , если применить к каждой, дает нужный результат...

Объединить не соображу как, пробовал так :

SELECT SUM(t1.price * t1.vol) AS Stab1, SUM(t2.price * t2.vol) AS Stab2 FROM tab1 t1,tab2 t2 ...

-первый столбец правильно, остальные бредовые числа.

каждый SELECT к таблице объединяя через UNION выводит все в один столбец ....

итог нужен:

| Stab1 | Stab2 | Stab3 | Stab4 |

сумма    сумма   сумма   сумма

Comment: [Это ваш мульт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707881/191482), я полагаю?

Comment: нет конечно, но на мысль навела, правда ОШИБКА в запросе ... вот так   если :           SELECT t1 AS Stab1, t2 AS Stab2 FROM 
(SELECT SUM (price * vol) as t1 FROM tab1 UNION ALL
SELECT SUM (price * vol) as t2 FROM tab2)